# How to create new columns with count values based on the values from another column SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using Big Query and my table looks like this:

> ### ID Month Values
>
> 1234 Aug  P
>   1234 Sept  P
>   3456 Aug   D
>   3456 Sept  D
>   4567 Aug   P
>   4567 Sept  D

I want to generate new column for each month and ID containing P,D as column names and values is their count for each ID and Month. Like below:

> ID   Month   P    D
>     1234  Aug    1    0
>     1234  Sept   1    0
>     3456  Aug    0    1
>     3456  Sept   0    1
>     4567  Aug    1    0
>     4567  Sept   1    1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, month, IF(value='P', 1, 0) AS p, IF(value='D', 1, 0) AS d
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

you can play with above using dummy data from your question

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1234 id, 'Aug' month, 'P' value UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234, 'Sept', 'P' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3456, 'Aug', 'D' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3456, 'Sept', 'D' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4567, 'Aug', 'P' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4567, 'Sept', 'D' 
)
SELECT id, month, IF(value='P', 1, 0) AS p, IF(value='D', 1, 0) AS d
FROM `project.dataset.table`
-- ORDER BY id
```

with result

```
Row id      month   p   d    
1   1234    Aug     1   0    
2   1234    Sept    1   0    
3   3456    Aug     0   1    
4   3456    Sept    0   1    
5   4567    Aug     1   0    
6   4567    Sept    0   1
```

In case if you have duplicate rows in your table and need to count values vs. just presenting them (as it is in above query) you can use below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1234 id, 'Aug' month, 'P' value UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234, 'Sept', 'P' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234, 'Sept', 'P' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3456, 'Aug', 'D' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3456, 'Sept', 'D' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4567, 'Aug', 'P' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4567, 'Sept', 'D' 
)
SELECT id, month, COUNTIF(value='P') AS p, COUNTIF(value='D') AS d
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY id, month
-- ORDER BY id, month
```

with result

```
Row id      month   p   d    
1   1234    Aug     1   0    
2   1234    Sept    2   0    
3   3456    Aug     0   1    
4   3456    Sept    0   1    
5   4567    Aug     1   0    
6   4567    Sept    0   1
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. Excellent answer. I also used a nested query to achieve the solution. Is there any downside of using that?

Comment: in many cases having nested queries is not a problem. Meantime check the answers on your other question and act on it :o)